# How to use PostgreSQL hstore/json with JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jdbctemplate, hstore

Is there a way to use PostgreSQL json/hstore with `JdbcTemplate`? esp query support.

for eg:

hstore:

```
INSERT INTO hstore_test (data) VALUES ('"key1"=>"value1", "key2"=>"value2", "key3"=>"value3"')

SELECT data -> 'key4' FROM hstore_test
SELECT item_id, (each(data)).* FROM hstore_test WHERE item_id = 2
```

for Json

```
insert into jtest (data) values ('{"k1": 1, "k2": "two"}');
select * from jtest where data ->> 'k2' = 'two';
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Although quite late for an answer (for the insert part), I hope it might be useful someone else:

Take the key/value pairs in a HashMap:

```
Map<String, String> hstoreMap = new HashMap<>();
hstoreMap.put("key1", "value1");
hstoreMap.put("key2", "value2");

PGobject jsonbObj = new PGobject();
jsonbObj.setType("json");
jsonbObj.setValue("{\"key\" : \"value\"}");
```

use one of the following way to insert them to PostgreSQL:

1)

```
jdbcTemplate.update(conn -> {
     PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement( "INSERT INTO table (hstore_col, jsonb_col) VALUES (?, ?)" );
     ps.setObject( 1, hstoreMap );
     ps.setObject( 2, jsonbObj );
});
```

2)

```
jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO table (hstore_col, jsonb_col) VALUES(?,?)", 
new Object[]{ hstoreMap, jsonbObj }, new int[]{Types.OTHER, Types.OTHER});
```

3) 
Set hstoreMap/jsonbObj in the POJO (hstoreCol of type Map and jsonbObjCol is of type PGObject)

```
BeanPropertySqlParameterSource sqlParameterSource = new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource( POJO );
sqlParameterSource.registerSqlType( "hstore_col", Types.OTHER );
sqlParameterSource.registerSqlType( "jsonb_col", Types.OTHER );
namedJdbcTemplate.update( "INSERT INTO table (hstore_col, jsonb_col) VALUES (:hstoreCol, :jsonbObjCol)", sqlParameterSource );
```

And to get the value:

```
(Map<String, String>) rs.getObject( "hstore_col" ));
((PGobject) rs.getObject("jsonb_col")).getValue();
```

Comment: surprisingly, it still did not work for me. an upgrade to the latest postgres version driver fixed that.

Comment: God bless you for the method #3. Before I found it, I had spend several hours on trying to insert a valid JSON string via jdbcTemplate (it was keeping escaping JSON every time)

Answer (score 5):

Even easier than `JdbcTemplate`, you can use the [`Hibernate Types`](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types) open-source project to persist HStore properties.

First, you need the Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate-types.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Then, assuming you have the following `Book` entity:

```
@Entity(name = "Book")
@Table(name = "book")
@TypeDef(name = "hstore", typeClass = PostgreSQLHStoreType.class)
public static class Book {
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
 
    @NaturalId
    @Column(length = 15)
    private String isbn;
 
    @Type(type = "hstore")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "hstore")
    private Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
 
    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

Notice that we annotated the `properties` entity attribute with the `@Type` annotation and we specified the `hstore` type that was previously defined via `@TypeDef` to use the [`PostgreSQLHStoreType`](https://vladmihalcea.com/map-postgresql-hstore-jpa-entity-property-hibernate/) custom Hibernate Type.

Now, when storing the following `Book` entity:

```
Book book = new Book();
 
book.setIsbn("978-9730228236");
book.getProperties().put("title", "High-Performance Java Persistence");
book.getProperties().put("author", "Vlad Mihalcea");
book.getProperties().put("publisher", "Amazon");
book.getProperties().put("price", "$44.95");
 
entityManager.persist(book);
```

Hibernate executes the following SQL INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO book (isbn, properties, id)
VALUES (
    '978-9730228236',
    '"author"=>"Vlad Mihalcea",
     "price"=>"$44.95", "publisher"=>"Amazon",
     "title"=>"High-Performance Java Persistence"',
    1
)
```

And, when we fetch the `Book` entity, we can see that all properties are fetched properly:

```
Book book = entityManager
.unwrap(Session.class)
.bySimpleNaturalId(Book.class)
.load("978-9730228236");
 
assertEquals(
    "High-Performance Java Persistence",
    book.getProperties().get("title")
);

assertEquals(
    "Vlad Mihalcea",
    book.getProperties().get("author")
);
```

Comment: Hi , is there a way to store Map<Object,Object> withing a custom Converter for each object ?

Comment: Converters are very limited as they don't give you access to the JDBC `PreparedStatement`. So, they don't work for any DB-specific type. You can still try it if you want, but I'd always pick a Hibernate Type.

Comment: thank you for the answer , I would like to understand how the HStoreType works , I persisted a Map of Object Object , what I noticed he storing the toString value , and from database to object I can't get the right object , that's why am asking for converter or should I implement my owen HStoreType for object

Comment: The code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types), so you can easily debug it to see how it works. Enjoy learning more about it.

Answer (score 1):

While this question was about Spring's JDBC Template, some users might have an option of using [jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org) instead, which has the `jooq-postgres-extensions` module that implements support for `HSTORE` and other data types like `CIDR`, `INET`, `DATERANGE`, `INT4RANGE`, `INT8RANGE`, `TSRANGE`, `TSTZRANGE`, `LTREE`, and possibly others, in the future. `JSON`, `JSONB`, and `XML` types are supported too, without the above extensions module.

Your queries can then be written as follows:

```java
ctx.insertInto(HSTORE_TEST)
   .columns(HSTORE_TEST.DATA)
   .values(Hstore.valueOf(Map.of("key1", "value1", "key2", "value2")))
   .execute();

ctx.insertInto(JTEST)
   .columns(JTEST.DATA)
   .values(JSONB.valueOf(
        """
        {"k1": 1, "k2": "two"}
        """))
   .execute();
```

jOOQ will take care of the data type conversion (for `HSTORE`) and the required casts of bind variables (e.g. `?::hstore`) transparently.

Some [JSON functions and operators](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/json-functions/) are available out of the box, for everything else, you can use [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/)

Disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOQ.